# Cycling an array on click

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that has more than 12 elements, i.e.[ a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]

In UI below this is how I want it to be displayed in a 3 X 3 grid.

`a b c
d e f
g h <>`

Where <> is a load more button

On each subsequent load more button click I need to display like

`i j k
l a b
c d <>`

and so on

`e f g
h i j
k l <>`

Basically I want to loop into the same array. At a time 8 elements will be shown along with <> button. I have the logic to display in grid ready, but load more I am having difficulty. Any guidance on how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
var start = 0;
var arr = [ a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l];

function nextChunk(howMany) {
    var result = [];
    while (howMany--) {
        result.push(arr[start]);
        start = (start + 1) % arr.length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Most of the answers resolved my problem, however I marked this as an answer because I was able to grasp the logic much quicker than others.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop and generate the HTML

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
  // variable for holding current index position
  curPos = 0;

var res = document.getElementById('result');

function gen() {
  // initialize an empty string
  var str = '';
  // iterate 8 times
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    // generate the string
    str += arr[(curPos + j) % arr.length] // get the array element 
      + (j % 3 == 2 ? '<br>' : '&nbsp;&nbsp;'); // ad `br` tag based on position
  }
  // add the button at the end
  str += '<button onclick="gen()">&lt;&gt;</button>'
  // update current index position
  curPos = (curPos + 8) % arr.length;
  // update the html content
  res.innerHTML = str;
}
// call the function to generate initial content
gen();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav for the response.

Comment: @Mozak : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure over the wanted part for generating the values.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
    getNext = function (array, n) {
        var p = 0;
        return function () {
            var i, a = [];
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                (i % 3) || a.push([]);
                a[a.length - 1].push(array[p]);
                p++;
                p %= array.length;
            }
            document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = a.map(function (b) { return b.join(' '); }).join('<br>') + ' <button onclick="getNext()">&lt;&gt; </button>'
        };
    }(array, 8);

getNext();
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I created simple function that will offset the array by positive number. It will produce new array, and you can use the same logic to display the grid that you already have.

```
function offsetArray(arr, offset){
    return arr.reduce( function(prev, curr, i) {
        prev.push(arr[ (i+offset) % arr.length ]); return prev
    }, [])
}


offsetArray(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'], 1) //returns ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "a"]
offsetArray(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'], 5) //returns ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This just simple solution based on static variable on javascript

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="row">
    <div id="mydata"></div>
    <button onclick="ShowNext();">Get Next</button>
</div>

<script>
    function MyClass() {
        
        this.MyData = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'];  // Public variable 

        this.UpdateGrid = function () {  // Public Method
            if (typeof MyClass.currentIndex == 'undefined') {
                // It has not... perform the initialization
                MyClass.currentIndex = 0;
            }
            var myhtml = '';
            var limit = MyClass.currentIndex + 8;
           
            for (var i = MyClass.currentIndex; i <limit; i++)
            {
                myhtml += this.MyData[i] + " ";
                if (i % 3 === 0)
                    myhtml += "<br/>";

            }
            $('#mydata').html(myhtml);
            MyClass.currentIndex += 8;
            alert(MyClass.currentIndex);
        };
    }

    function ShowNext()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.UpdateGrid();
    }
    
     

</script>
```